# OAuth request is not working for Languages url when I use access token

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, oauth-2.0

When I do an outh request from my App to laguages url from a repository from Github using the url provided by the API using an access token I get the following response

```
{
  "message":"Resource not accessible by integration",
  "documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages"
}
```

The code looks like this

```
OAuthRequest oAuthRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, languagesUrl);
oAuthRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

The scopes are "user:email,public_repo"

when I remove the token from the header shows me the languages from the repo but of course with a limit of 60 request per hour... On Thursday It was working OK but since yesterday it's not and the others links of the repositories works fine with the same token.
Do anyone
someone has had the same problem??

Comment: The little information bubble at the [`documentation_url`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages) says _"Enabled for GitHub Apps"_. Is this relevant considering [this document](https://developer.github.com/apps/differences-between-apps/)?